# Question is inacessible due to invalid utf-8 character in a title

Tags: bug, status-completed

This question is broken because apparently the server side script tries to redirect the question to itself multiple times, since the question has an invalid utf-8 character in the title, it's stuck in an infinite redirect loop trying to correct its title, but fails.

[Pronunciation and meaning of ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1472/pronunciation-and-meaning-of-%EE%93%BB)

This is confirmed to be broken in the latest version of chrome and firefox under Windows 7 64-bit (Japanese version).

Comment: We are investigating; the utf-8 itself seems fine (code-point decimal 58619), so it is something more subtle. As I say: we're investigating. Frustratingly, it works perfectly on my local machine, so I can't repro conveniently. Thanks for reporting what is clearing an error.

Comment: @MarcGravell, FYI, I got "Content-Type:text/html; charset=us-ascii" in first response from server. Could that charset be issue?

Comment: @MarcGravell FYI, the first three [HTTP request/response headers recorded by Google Chrome](https://gist.github.com/1318673) during the infinite loop.

Comment: FWIW: wget "http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1472/pronunciation-and-meaning-of-%EE%93%BB" loops as well.
Full log at: http://pastebin.com/vNy6unYj

Comment: @Axioplase ultimately that's the same question, so that isn't unexpected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in IIS (the underlying Microsoft web-server product that hosts all these sites). If you really want the gory details, see this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913830/is-iis-performing-an-illegal-character-substitution-if-so-how-to-stop-it. For now, I will add a defensive check on this particular sequence, but we are pursuing the issue with Microsoft (and with the horde of stackoverflow users).

clarification: this is now [filed with Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/697981/asp-net-mvc-via-iis-performs-invalid-unicode-url-translation); for now, we have a workaround in place so that the question is reachable.

Comment: The bug is still there, or something very similar. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233850/redirect-loop-after-editing-a-question-title-ending-with-no-break-space-questio