# Could/should there be a way to write and save a draft of a question?

Tags: support, feature-request, questions

I was wanting to ask a question, but realized I left at home a reference book that would have helped me formulate it.  So I was gonna start the question, save it as a draft, then finish it at home, but realized there is no obvious way to do it.  I see that every few minutes, it autosaves a draft and show `draft saved`, but I'm betting this is cookie-based and this "draft" could not be carried between browsers to be edited.

Since questions can be edited anyway, a draft is simply another edit of a question, just an edit with incomplete thoughts.  I was thinking maybe you could just add the text "**[DRAFT]**" in the title, but you probably wouldn't want a draft "published" so that people could see it until you're ready.  From a software standpoint, the only difference between a draft and an actual post would be a differing 'published' flag on the database entry.

Since we "modified" the site with some type of script to accommodate displaying furigana, I'm wondering if it could also be modified to include a 'published' flag to allow for creating drafts.  And if possible, would it even be worth the time/effort of doing?

Thoughts?

P.P. (Pre-Post) - I notice that one of the tags you *must* include is [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).  So it seems that something like this is possible.  Who do these feature requests go to?  The JL&U admins, or some higher up StackExchange people?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238) explains the existing draft system.  You essentially get one question draft and one answer draft at a time, and they expire after a week or after you submit.

It looks like the draft is stored on the server, so in your case it would have worked.

A quick glance at [the list of draft feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=save+a+draft+of+a+question) show that a lot of the requests for manual control over drafts have been declined.  But, your idea about publishing looks a little different than those requests, so you can probably try arguing for it again.

Regarding the last bit, the StackExchange team monitors all of the meta sites (as shown by [Marc Gravell's](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/127/marc-gravell) [help fixing an encoding bug yesterday](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/566/question-is-inacessible-due-to-invalid-utf-8-character-in-a-title/567#567)).  If you want, features that may be of use to the wider network can be posted on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) instead, where it will get more exposure and input from the rest of the StackExchange community (for better or worse).